# TYPO3 9.5.3 User Rights on Root Pages and Slug autofill

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I got a little problem with TYPO3 9.5.3:

My root page is the topmost object. And now I have given a user the right to edit it. This is also possible but the user cannot edit the translated root page because he has no right to do so. Then I thought to myself I have to assign the right separately but this is not possible because I get a 500 error for the user. Then I set a folder around the root and have the user the right for the folder against.

Now it had worked with the user but now there is another problem: The URL is automatically set by the slug to dev.vm/de/de/1 but it should be dev.vm/de/de/. 
Could someone help me either with the rights or with the url ?

Thank you

So this is once the pagestree without folder and once with
[without](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tFO7.jpg)
[with](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwvEl.png)

[And these are the rights I have to give the backend user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qO81i.png)

[But if this user now wants to edit the root page like the metadata or so then he gets this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwen4.png)

So I thought I'd give him the other rights to the pages now but then there's another bug too

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/955oM.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAj7P.png)

[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBzCA.png)

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot or visualisation of how the page tree looks like and explain what "set a folder around the root" and "have the user the right for the folder against" means (or looks like)? Thx

Comment: Thanks for the answer I have added pictures for you. Yes I gave the user the rights for the folder and then Typo3 recognized that the user also has rights for the translated pages. But I would like to build it without a folder.